# Probability of generating a number bigger than all previously generated

Tags: probability-theory

Given a distribution with density function $p(x)$ and randomly generated numbers $n_1, n_2, ..., n_t$ from this distribution I want to answer next question:

What is a probability that next generated number will be bigger than maximum of $n_1, n_2, ..., n_t$ in at least $\alpha$ times?

Comment: What does in at least $alpha$ times mean? Probability t+1th number is biggest is 1/(t+1) for continuous distributions.

Comment: $/alpha$ is some coefficient, for example 2. This means that I want to find probability that next number will be at least 2 times bigger than any we have.

Answer (score 0):

Let $N_1,\ldots,N_{t+1}$ be the corresponding i.i.d random variables each with density $p$ (I assume with respect to the Lebesgue measure). Let $F$ denote the cdf of this distribution.

Then by independence
$$\begin{aligned}P(N_{t+1}\geq \alpha \max(N_1,\ldots, N_t))
&=\int 1_{x_{t+1}\geq \alpha n_1}\ldots 1_{x_{t+1}\geq \alpha n_t}f(n_1)\ldots f(n_{t+1}) d\lambda(n_1)\ldots d\lambda(n_{t+1})\\
&= \int \left(\int 1_{n_{t+1}\geq \alpha n_1}f(n_1)\right)^t f(n_{t+1}) d\lambda(n_{t+1})\\
&= \int \left[F(\frac{n_{t+1}}{\alpha})\right]^t f(n_{t+1}) d\lambda(n_{t+1})
\\ &= E\left(\left[F(\frac{N_{t+1}}{\alpha})\right]^t\right)
\end{aligned}$$