# Probability of a number being larger than previous number

Tags: probability

Given a set of 100 numbers - randomly "draw" 5 numbers (duplicates allowed).

identify the highest 2 values from this set.

What is the probability that the next draw (ie a 6th number) will be larger than either of those 2 values ?

for curiosity sake, I created a small poll to see how people would choose between 2 options related to this question:
http://www.easypolls.net/poll.html?p=5dd692d1e4b033f78236d9af
(still gathering results .. I'll show results in a day or two)

Somewhat related question:
[Probability of generating a number bigger than all previously generated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1547635/probability-of-generating-a-number-bigger-than-all-previously-generated)
however, much more generic than what I'm after, and I'll be honest, I can't make heads of it :) so looking for some help here.

Example:
5 numbers generated:  13, 25, 39, 67, 85

Largest two are 67 and 85.

Results of 6th number that could be larger than either of them is:
68-100
so in this case, it's 33%

(yes, i could have also stated larger than the 2nd largest, but that seemed clunkier to say :) )

Comment: What do you mean by "larger than either of those two values"?  Larger than both of them or larger than the smaller one?

Comment: Either: as in, larger than either 1 or the other.  I'll put up an example to make it clear.

Comment: Duplicates allowed?  Well, that makes things a bit more frustrating.  Had duplicates not been allowed, this would have been very simply $\frac{2}{6}$, noting that the order of the six numbers drawn is equally likely to be any of the available orders, and the position of the sixth number within the order is equally likely to have been any of the six positions, two of which correspond to being the largest or second largest overall.

Comment: @JMoravitz interesting .. I hadn't thought of it like that, neat ... .. and sorry, didn't realize the duplicates would cause additional frustration!!  LOL  ;)

Comment: The probability that there are no duplicates is about $.985$ so $\frac26$ must be a good estimate. If duplicates are allowed, can we decide whether the probability is greater or less than $\frac26$ without much additional calculation?  Probably, we can analyze the case with exactly one duplicate, and consider the case of more than one duplicate negligible.

Comment: Followiing the procedure in my previous comment I get the estimate $.3318\overline{3}$

Comment: @saulspatz, I get an exact answer that differs significantly from your estimate. Could you please take a look at my approach?

Answer (score 1):

Time being symmetric, let's think backwards, and pick the "sixth" number *first*.  Then it will be greater than the second largest of the "previous" five numbers if and only if at least four of those five numbers are strictly less than it. If the sixth number is $k$, with $0\le k\le99$, the probability of that happening is

$$P(k)=\left(k\over100\right)^5+5\left(k\over100\right)^4\left(100-k\over100\right)=\left(1\over100\right)^4\left(5k^4-{1\over25}k^5\right)$$

so the overall probability is

$$\begin{align}
{1\over100}\sum_{k=0}^{99}P(k)
&=\left(1\over100\right)^5\left(5\sum_{k=1}^{99}k^4-{1\over25}\sum_{k=1}^{99}k^5 \right)\\
\end{align}$$

From the [Faulhaber formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Examples), we have

$$5\sum_{k=1}^{99}k^4-{1\over25}\sum_{k=1}^{99}k^5
={6\cdot99^5+15\cdot99^4+10\cdot99^3-99\over6}-\cdot{2\cdot99^6+6\cdot99^5+5\cdot99^4-99^2\over300}
=3283333350$$

hence the overall probability is

$$\left(1\over100\right)^5(3283333350)
=0.328333335$$

Note, this is smaller than saulspatz's estimate, $0.3318\overline3$, in comments below the OP -- it's more than three times saulspatz's reduction from the no-duplicates answer of $1/3$ (about $0.005$ less, as opposed to $0.0015$). I'd be curious to see an explanation as to why that is; I hope it's not because I made a mistake.

Comment: Thanks ... gtad I posted this here, this is way over my head!!  hehe  Learn something new every day :)